# React Redux state undefined in mapStateToProps

Tags: react-redux

I am having trouble with state being undefined in `mapStateToProps` in my React Redux app. The only way I can get it to work is to use `store.getState()`, but I know this is not the correct way to do it. If I log the state to the console, I get undefined (and if I try to map state to properties, I also get undefined). I am stumped as to why this is happening. I feel like I am missing something fundamental, but I just can't put my finger on it. I know using Redux would not be practical normally for a simple app like this, but I just wanted to practise using it. Any help would be appreciated!

This is my `mapStateToProps` function:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state); //Returns undefined
  tempState = store.getState(); //Why do I have to do this?
  return {
    text: tempState.reduxText,
    author: tempState.reduxAuthor,
    backgroundColor: tempState.reduxBackgroundColor,
    buttonColor: tempState.reduxButtonColor,
    textColor: tempState.reduxTextColor,
    tweetURL: tempState.reduxTweetURL,
    textFade: tempState.reduxTextFade
  }
}
```

These are my actions and action creators:

```js
const CHANGE_QUOTE_ACTION = 'CHANGE_QUOTE_ACTION';
const CHANGE_QUOTE_TRANSITION = 'CHANGE_QUOTE_TRANSITION';

const changeQuoteActionCreator = () => {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_QUOTE_ACTION,
    payload: {
      reduxText: quoteArr[quoteRandomIndex][0],
      reduxAuthor: quoteArr[quoteRandomIndex][1],
      reduxTweetURL: 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=\"' + quoteArr[quoteRandomIndex][0] + '\" ' + quoteArr[quoteRandomIndex][1],
      reduxTextFade: 'textVisible '
    }
  }
}

const changeQuoteTransitionActionCreator = () => {
  while (quoteArr[quoteRandomIndex][0] == store.getState().reduxText) {
    quoteRandomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }
  while ('container-fluid ' + colorArr[colorRandomIndex] + '-color' == store.getState().reduxBackgroundColor) {
    colorRandomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  };
  return {
    type: CHANGE_QUOTE_TRANSITION,
    payload: {
      reduxBackgroundColor: 'container-fluid ' + colorArr[colorRandomIndex] + '-color',
      reduxButtonColor: 'btn btn-outline shadow-none text-white ' + colorArr[colorRandomIndex] + '-color ' + colorArr[colorRandomIndex] + '-hoverColor',
      reduxTextColor: colorArr[colorRandomIndex] + '-textColor',
      reduxTextFade: 'textInvisible'
    }
  }
}

const asyncChangeQuoteActionCreator = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(changeQuoteTransitionActionCreator());
    setTimeout(function () {
      dispatch(changeQuoteActionCreator());
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

This is my reducer:

```js
initialReduxState = {
  reduxText: '',
  reduxAuthor: '',
  reduxBackgroundColor: 'container-fluid ' + colorArr[initialColorRandomIndex] + '-color',
  reduxButtonColor: 'btn btn-outline shadow-none text-white ' + colorArr[initialColorRandomIndex] + '-color ' + colorArr[initialColorRandomIndex] + '-hoverColor',
  reduxTextColor: colorArr[initialColorRandomIndex] + '-textColor',
  reduxTweetURL: ''
}

//Redux reducer

const changeQuoteReducer = (state = initialReduxState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_QUOTE_ACTION:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { reduxText: action.payload.reduxText, reduxAuthor: action.payload.reduxAuthor, reduxTweetURL: action.payload.reduxTweetURL, reduxTextFade: action.payload.reduxTextFade });
    case CHANGE_QUOTE_TRANSITION:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { reduxBackgroundColor: action.payload.reduxBackgroundColor, reduxButtonColor: action.payload.reduxButtonColor, reduxTextColor: action.payload.reduxTextColor, reduxTextFade: action.payload.reduxTextFade })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is connecting to the store:

```js
const store = Redux.createStore(
  changeQuoteReducer,
  Redux.applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk.default)
);

const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;

const connect = ReactRedux.connect;
```

This is mapDispatchToProps:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    changeQuoteDispatch: () => {
      dispatch(asyncChangeQuoteActionCreator())
    }
  }
}
```

Subscribing to the store, dispatching to the store and connecting Redux to React:

```js
store.subscribe(mapStateToProps);

store.dispatch(mapDispatchToProps);

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Presentational);
```

Comment: You should remove `store.subscribe(mapStateToProps);` and `store.dispatch(mapDispatchToProps);` why are you doing this?

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I have been following FreeCodeCamp and I think I misread the following: 

'Note: Behind the scenes, React Redux uses the store.subscribe() method to implement mapStateToProps()'

and 

'Behind the scenes, React Redux is using Redux's store.dispatch() to conduct these dispatches with mapDispatchToProps(). This is similar to how it uses store.subscribe() for components that are mapped to state.'

And thought that it meant that the user had to manually do this, whereas on re-reading it it was saying that React Redux does this! Problem solved!!